# Custom Header Title react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanna make custom header title in react native that render a greeting text,
this is the logic code of the greeting text

```js
greeting = () => {
     const date = new Date();
     let hours = date.getHours();
     let status =
         hours < 12
             ? "Selamat Pagi"
             : hours <= 18 && hours >= 12
             ? "Selamat Siang"
             : "Selamat Malam";
     return status;
};
```

Comment: We're probably going to need some more context around what you're wanting to do here. I'm guessing the current output is not expected, if so what is the expect input/output you're not getting?

Comment: You need to fill in more details to your question. What problems are you facing with this snippet. Or if you want to add any additional snippets where this code block is being called. The current details are insufficient to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

sry, this is the answer i think

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor:'white'}}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


function App() {
  const [greet, setGreet] = useState('')
  const findGreet = () => {
    const hrs = new Date().getHours()
    if (hrs == 0 || hrs < 12) return setGreet('Pagi')
    if (hrs == 1 || hrs < 17) return setGreet('Siang')
    setGreet('Malam')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    findGreet()
  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerTitle: `Selamat ${greet}`,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0, 
          }, }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).